# Dynamically updating variables in ANTLR generated parser

Tags: python, antlr

I am writing an EBNF for a simple language. One of the capabilities of the language is computing expressions and storing in variables. For example:

```
A = 5
B = A + 2
C = B / (A * 2)
D = C - B + A
```

I am generating a Python parser using ANTLR and I am able to compute the values just fine and build up my data structures.

I have an extra requirement though. If the value of variable A is updated later on in the code, I need B, C and D to get new values corresponding to A.
So far, my idea is to store the entire expression/equation for each variable. And then once the parser has completed the first pass, I re-evaluate all those stored expressions to get updated values.

But I am wondering if ANTLR itself provides some hooks for doing such a thing? Like a multi-pass thing of sorts?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Antlr does not offer such feature.

You would have to keep the parse tree of each expression, and the dependency list of each variable to be able to re-evaluate those that are depending of one that has been changed directly or indirectly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking of doing. Was hoping someone out there would have done something like this already. Oh well.